# MongoDB find operation throws OperationFailure: Cannot update value

Tags: mongodb, aws-documentdb

I have an application that uses MongoDB (on AWS DocumentDB) to stores documents with a large string in one of its fields which we call field X.
Few notes to start:

1. I'm using pymongo so the method names you might see here are taken from there
2. As of the nature of field X it is not being indexed

On field X we use MongoDB find method using a query with regex condition limiting it by both **maxTimeMS** and **limit** to a small amount of results.

---

When we get the results we iterate the cursor to fetch all the results to a list (inline loop).

Most of the times the query works properly but I'm starting to get more and more of the following error:

```
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: Cannot update value (error code 14)
```

This is being thrown after the query return a cursor and we iterating the results and occurs after trying to `_refresh` the cursor connection by calling the `next` method and being thrown by `_check_command_response` at its last line meaning this is a default exception(?).

The query:

```
collection.find(condition).max_time_ms(MAX_QUERY_TIME_MS).sort(sort_order) \
            .limit(RESULT_LIMIT)
results = [document for document in cursor] # <--- here we get the error
```

Stack trace:

```
pymongo/helpers.py in _check_command_response at line 155
pymongo/cursor.py in __send_message at line 982
pymongo/cursor.py in _refresh at line 1104
pymongo/cursor.py in next at line 1189
common/my_code.py in <listcomp> at line xxx
```

I'm trying to understand the origin of the exception to handle it correctly or use a different approach for handling the cursor.
what is being updated at the refresh method of the cursor that might
    throw the above exception?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Question is useless without any code and a full stack trace.

Comment: "Cannot update value" string does not occur in MongoDB server source code, what database are you using?

Comment: Using AWS DocumentDb

Comment: DocumentDB is not MongoDB. DocumentDB is a proprietary Amazon database that exposes an interface that implements some MongoDB functionality that could be [using PostgreSQL](https://www.enterprisedb.com/blog/documentdb-really-postgresql) under the hood. DocumentDB is [far from being fully compatible](https://www.mongodb.com/atlas-vs-amazon-documentdb) with MongoDB.
Sounds like you ran into one of the incompatibilities/bugs.

Comment: oh i see, thanks! i didn't know that i will check over DocumentDB documentation

Comment: @Swarrly were you able to solve this issue? Were there any steps taken to resolve this?

Comment: @sameerasy We improved the query performance wise and reduce the limit size